# Mesh to world vector translation

Tags: 3d, matrix, vector

Suppose I have a world defined in typical OpenGL coords.. then the up vector defined for this space is (0,1,0).

Now, if I load a model that is defined with (0,0,1) as its up vector, what are the matrix operation(s) that I need to carry out here to arrive at the 4x4 transformation matrix for the model?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The up vector being different basically means that the model is in a different space, where Z inwards represents that what you regard as Y up. To compensate for this, rotate the model vertices 90 degrees over the X-axis (in the right direction). Draw the axes on paper, it'll be clear in a jiffy.

Think of it as this: if you were to rotate the up vector 0, 0, 1 -- how would you do it to make it 0, 1, 0?

Use Google for all about building rotation matrices. Or use glRotate() for a quick test.